# Connect Laravel with MS Access as Second database

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, ms-access-2013

I have three problems.

1. Access MS Access with Laravel application.
2. Connect MS Access as second database with Laravel application, my first database is mysql.
3. When any new records added in MS Access database, my script copy that records from MS Access to MySql.

Comment: Any updates to this?

Comment: you can connect mysql with odbc connection inside the access and link the table which you want to use

Answer (score 1):

Create link in MS Access with your MySql database table and now both databases have same data every time.

Procedure for link MySql table in MS Access database.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html